# C#: Send XML over https/SSL3 with client/server certificates

Tags: c#, xml, ssl, https

I need to develop a C# client able to post XML docs into a SAP Bussiness Connector 4.6.

The Client:
.NET until 4.6, VS 2013 available, SO Win 8.1 Pro 64 bits.

The Server:
Windows 2000, with SAP Business Connector 4.6 (it's really equal to WebMethods 4.6), configured with https and Client certificate as authentication method. The server has a certificate that doesn't match the URL used in local development against it.

I'm trying several .NET methods and clients. I'm actually trying httpClient to connect with BC, without success.

The actual code is very similar to this:

```
try
{
    System.Net.Http.HttpClient client;
    //HttpClient uses the HttpMessageHandler pipeline for sending and receiving requests
    //WebRequestHandler derives from HttpClientHandler but adds properties that generally only are available on full .NET
    System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler wrHandler = new System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler();
    System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate x509cert = System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.CreateFromCertFile("MyClientCertificate.crt");
    wrHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(x509cert);
    client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(wrHandler);

    //THIS SKIPS SERVER CERTIFICATE                    
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
    System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage();
    request.Method = System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Post;
    request.RequestUri = new System.Uri("https://192.168.12.12:3333/invoke/wm.PartnerMgr.flows.UCLR.0000000001:ORDERS");
    request.Content = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(CtrXMLToSendContent.Text, Encoding.UTF8, CtrClient1MediaType.Text);               

    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

    Task<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage> taskResponse = client.SendAsync(request);
    if (taskResponse.Wait(-1)) //-1 = infinite
    {
        //Response received
        System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = taskResponse.Result;
        TextResponseData.Text = response.ToString();
        Task<String> taskResponseStr = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        taskResponseStr.Wait();
        String responseContent = taskResponseStr.Result;
        TextResponseContent.Text = responseContent;
    }
    else
    {
        TextClient1Infolog.AppendText("Wait ");
    }
}
catch (Exception _e)
{
    TextClient1Infolog.AppendText("Error :" + Environment.NewLine);
    TextClient1Infolog.AppendText(_e.ToString());
}
```

When I launch it, it throws an exception, giving this error:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

There's no server response at all I can explore or debug. I think it's a problem of handshaking SSL protocol. I must insist: There's no response text from server, no 402 or 404 message errors at all: Nothing is received.

Firefox over that direction says no connection. IE, with TSL 1.0, 1.2 and 1.3 activated, says it cannot connect; activating SSL 3.0 and reopening page says there's a problem with server certificate (yes, because I'm accesing from local network, where certificate states for something like "this.server.com").

Fiddler4 doesn't say me much (and autocertificates appears to be confusing something), SoapUI appears to be not very useful here (haven't see way to set certificates and SSL handshakes).
Found a tool (TestSSLServer, link: http://www.bolet.org/TestSSLServer/) that gave me this info:

> Supported versions:  SSLv3 TLSv1.0 Deflate compression: no Supported
>   cipher suites (ORDER IS NOT SIGNIFICANT):
>     SSLv3
>        RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
>        RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
>        RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
>        RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC2_CBC_40_MD5
>        RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
>        RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
>        RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
>     (TLSv1.0: idem)
>   ---------------------- Server certificate(s):
>   188659f61762af0de690bf5cb76a8554e7ff7f23: CN=my.server.com,
>   OU=Domain Control Validated
>   ---------------------- Minimal encryption strength:     weak encryption (40-bit) Achievable encryption strength:  strong encryption
>   (96-bit or more) BEAST status: vulnerable CRIME status: protected

So I suppose I have to force SSL3 handshake (I think this is OK in my code), validate server certificate (too)... perhaps I must do something with client certificate. 
Must I generate one for my client computer and load it? How can I generate one with one of the encriptions of the TestSSLServer's list? Wich file should be installed in what computer?

And I'm open to hear about other http clients (ServerXMLHTTP, etc) or tools able to test xml postings over xml. Any ideas about how to proceed for now?

Comment: Your server only supports old, outdated and insecure ciphers and protocols. You should update it as it is vulnerable and modern systems will not be able to connect to it.

Comment: Yes, I know. In some months that system will be replaced by a entirely new one. But now, I must face the actual one until it gets replaced... (sigh)
I'm trying to generate some self-signed certificates to see if installing them in server and configuring them in BC makes the trick of getting connection.

Comment: If you don't need access to the original server mentioned in the server certificate you can add the local test-server IP and the dns name mentioned in the certificate in the "hosts" file. Afterwards your computer would be able to access the local server by using the original server name. See http://superuser.com/questions/476666/editing-hosts-file-in-windows-8

Comment: Good idea! Applied...